# How to join two tables with ssp.class.php?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

As part of a project I have the jQuery DataTable API working to return data from a single "customers" table and it displays fine via an ajax call to a PHP file on the server.

However despite much reading and research I can't figure out how to use DataTables to display columns that return from a select statement. My PHP code is below which grabs the requested columns from the customers table:

```
<?php
        // DB table to use
        $table = 'customers';

        // Table's primary key
        $primaryKey = 'id';

        // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
        // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
        // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
        // indexes
        $columns = array(
            array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
            array( 'db' => 'first_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
            array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 2 ),
            array( 'db' => 'email',  'dt' => 3 )
        );

        // SQL server connection information
        $sql_details = array(
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => 'root',
            'db'   => 'NCI_BANK',
            'host' => 'localhost'
        );


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

        require( 'ssp.class.php' );

      echo json_encode(
          SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
      );    
   ?>
```

I would like to say something like:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts a 
JOIN customers b ON (a.customer_id = b.id) 
WHERE b.id = 8;"
```

This would return 13 columns.

Could anyone assist?

Comment: I'm not sure joins are supported with ssp.class.php. However there is another version which does from TecHelper (https://github.com/emran/ssp). It's also easy enough to write your own...?

Answer (score 0):

The query would be

```
("select * from Table 
   inner join Table1 
            on Table.campo= Table1.campo 
   inner join Table2
            on table.campo = Table2.Campo") Table
```